# Regular expression for find links in text

Tags: php, regex, match, matching

Help me, please, write regular expression for find all links (.com|.org|.ru) without tag <a> in text.

```
Example text:
 1. https://www.cyberforum.ru/newthread.php?do=newthread&f=323
 2. www.cyberforum.ru
 3. <a href="https://www.cyberforum.ru/newthread.php?do=newthread&f=323">www.cyberforum.ru/newthread.php?do=newthread&f=323</a>
 4. <a href="www.cyberforum.ru/newthread.php?do=newthread&f=323">www.cyberforum.ru/newthread.php?do=newthread&f=323</a>
```

Items 1,2 should be match with regular expression but 3,4 - no.
I tryed /(?<!["'<>])(\b(https?://)?([\w.]*(com|org|ru)[\w.?&=/]*)\b)/ but it is not work correctly.
[image]

Comment: If its always going to be `<a href="` or `<a href='` then you can do this *without* a regular expression by repeatedly calling `strpos()` in a loop, then parsing out the link between the quotes. As an idea for a non-regex approach which might be easier to wrap your head around.

Comment: Try if the `\K` *(PCRE)* works: `(?:<a.*?a>)\K|(\b(?:https?:|www\.)([\w.]+\.(?:com|org|ru)\S*))`

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

```
/**
 * Wraps links in <a></a> tag.
 * Skip links which are in href or in <a></a> tag already.
 *
 * @param string $text
 * @return string
 */
private static function replaceLinks(string $text): string
{
    return preg_replace_callback(
        '/\b(https?:\/\/)?([\w.-]*(\.com|\.org|\.ru|\.local)[\w.?&=\/]*)\b/',
        function ($matches) use ($text) {
            // checks previous char, skip links which are in href or in <a></a> tag
            $previousChar = $matches[0][1] > 0 ?  $text[--$matches[0][1]] : '';
            if (!in_array($previousChar, ['"', '\'', '<', '>', ';'])) {
                return "<a target='_blank' href=\"{$matches[0][0]}\">{$matches[0][0]}</a>";
            }

            // without replace
            return $matches[0][0];
        },
        $text,
        -1,
        $cont,
        PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way that combines DOM with RegEx. It restricts the change to the text content of element nodes inside the `body` and avoids modifying other nodes like comments or attributes.

What happens:

1. Iterate over the text nodes `/html/body//text()[not(ancestor::a)]`, avoid existing link elements
2. Use preg_split() to separate the text by matching http(s) URLs
3. Iterate over that list and add them (to a fragment) as a link if it is an URL or as a text node if not.
4. Replace the original text node with the new fragment.

```php
$html = <<<'HTML'
<html>
  <body>
    Some link http://example.tld to replace.
    <div>Another link http://example.tld/another to replace.</div>
    <a href="http://example.tld/in-link">http://example.tld/in-link</a>
  </body>
</html>
HTML;

$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($document);


$linkPattern = '\b(?:https?:\/\/)(?:[\w.?&=\/-]*)\b';
$splitPattern = '(('.$linkPattern.'))'; 
$matchPattern = '(^'.$linkPattern.'$)';

// iterate over text nodes inside the body
$expression = '/html/body//text()[not(ancestor::a)]';
foreach ($xpath->evaluate($expression) as $textNode) {
    // split the text content at the search string and capture any part
    $parts = preg_split(
        $splitPattern, 
        $textNode->textContent, 
        -1, 
        PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE
    );
    // here should be at least two parts
    if (count($parts) < 2) {
        continue;
    }
    // fragments allow to treat several nodes like one
    $fragment = $document->createDocumentFragment();
    foreach ($parts as $part) {
        // it's an URL
        if (preg_match($matchPattern, $part)) {
            // create the new a
            $fragment->appendChild(
                $a = $document->createElement('a')
            );
            $a->setAttribute('href', $part);
            $a->textContent = $part;
        } else {
            // add the part as a new text node
            $fragment->appendChild($document->createTextNode($part));
        }   
    }
    // replace the text node with the fragment
    $textNode->parentNode->replaceChild($fragment, $textNode);
}

echo $document->saveHTML();
```